# How to access Trigger type of diagram elements of a state machine diagram using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enterprise-architect

I have a state machine diagram. It has few trigger types of elements. How to access these using c#[image]
This image is of the element in the project browser

[image: This is the elements property window]

Comment: You want to get it from diagram or from package level ?

Comment: I have a statemachine element inside which there is a state machine diagram and all its objects. I need to fetch the triggers. Cannot find them inside the element or the diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you looped all diagram objects of the diagram you will get the trigger elememt as well.

```
Foreach(EA.DiagramObject dObj in selectedDiagram.DiagramObjects)
{
       EA.Element ele = Repository.GetElementByID(dObj .ElementID);
       if(ele.Type=="Trigger")
       {
           //You will get the trigger elements in the diagram
       }
}
```

Comment: It shows only state and statenode type of elements in the diagrams, although triggers are present using this

Comment: You got the trigger ? or still you didnt find ?

Comment: Yes, just got it. It is part of the parent element of the diagram not the diagram itself